# UITableView survey app and append data to apple numbers

Tags: swift

Ive tried to search up documentation and several tutorials but it seems like there's nothing out there. Maybe this is something simple to do, but I just cannot figure it out.

My goal is to make an application that has a series of questions that you fill in. Some tick boxes and some text fields where you fill in some more info. This survey would be on one VC and you scroll down through the questions. After all this I want to append the data to the apple numbers app on the iPad with a specific structure.

How would I go about this? Any resources you can recommend?

T.I.A

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you should generate and export a .csv file with all the data you collect in the app. Save that file to iCloud Drive or to another cloud solution you can integrate in your app, and then access it and open it using Numbers.

Comment: That sounds great thanks :) Tho how would I go about creating the actual survey on Xcode so that I have the data structure there? Would I just make a UITableView and input each section there as I want? Thankyou again for the speedy reply

Comment: You're welcome! Can't be specific about how to create the survey, it's up to you. But here's what I'd generally do: I'd keep all survey questions in a file into the app bundle, and I'd create a struct (let's say named `SurveyItem`) with 2 main properties: `question` & `answer`. Then, I'd create a function to load the questions and populate them to an array with `SurveyItem` objects. Answers given by a user would be set to the `answer` property of the respective `SurveyItem` object in the original array. Most importantly, that array would be used as the *datasource* of the tableview.